# Role exclusive commands not working // Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

My code is currently:

```
if (message.content == ",test") {
    if (message.member.roles.find("name", "images")) {        
        message.channel.send( {
            file: "http://www.drodd.com/images14/black11.jpg" // Or replace with FileOptions object
        });
    }
    if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "images")) { // This checks to see if they DONT have it, the "!" inverts the true/false
    message.reply('You need the \`images\` role to use this command.')
    .then(msg => {
      msg.delete(5000)
    })
    }
    message.delete(100); //Supposed to delete message
    return; // this returns the code, so the rest doesn't run. 
}
```

If the user has the role 'images' I want the bot to send the image when they say ",test" and I want the user's ",test" message to be deleted after some seconds. However, this doesn't seem to be working.

I have tried to send the image without the role checking and that works.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `message.member.roles.find("name", "images")` checks if the roles **EXISTS** in the guild. In order to find if someone has a role, you would use `message.member.roles.has(myRole)`. To find the ID of a role dynamically, you would use this: 
`let myRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Moderators").id;`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried that and it didn't work. Here is the console error: `TypeError: message.guild.roles.find(...).id.catch is not a function` http://prntscr.com/hrg72k

Comment: I've removed the catch as that may have caused problems.